# Ruby threads order of output?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm reading about Ruby Threads (I've never used Ruby before), and I'm surprised about the following code:

```
t1 = Thread.new { print "w"; Thread.pass; print "a"}
t2 = Thread.new { print "e"; Thread.pass; print "l"}
t1.join
t2.join
```

The book said that always will show "weal" and I don't understand why, because if they are real threads (as in other languages), it is not ensured that "w" will print before "e".

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: What book would it be? :)

Comment: Also, [`Thread.pass`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Thread.html#method-c-pass) is not guaranteed to pass execution to another thread.

Comment: The book is Humble Little Ruby Book: [link](http://www.humblelittlerubybook.com/book/hlrb.pdf)

Comment: @pianista - Note that this book is written for ruby 1.8.5, which was released almost 8 years ago. This sentence might be correct then.

Comment: The book doesn't seem to state that this will *always* print `weal`... Although, to be fair, it *should* state that this is merely one possible output, so as to confusing the reader.

Comment: It's really important to look at the publish date of books about languages and apps. Be very critical of ones that are over two years old, as languages, especially mainstream ones, move and evolve very quickly. Rails books and tutorials are especially prone to falling out of date quickly, as that is one fast-moving target. Trying to learn from a resource that is out of date is extremely frustrating for just the reason you've discovered.

Comment: Versions of Ruby up to 1.8.7 used [Green threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) for threading, and with those versions it would be possible to determine thread ordering (or at least it would be repeatable). Current Ruby versions use native threads which are scheduled by the OS, and aren’t predictable in the way green threads are. Testing with 1.8.7 shows that the code _does_ always print `weal`, with later versions the output is unpredictable.

Comment: Thank you @matt and BroiSatse, I will consider that the book may have something signatures older incomparison with the new version of Ruby

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the book or read it with care. You are of course right, the only guarantee is that `a` will show after `w` etc.

I have just tested your code and here are results after 10 runs:

```
weal
weal
ewal
wela
wael
wael
wela
ewla
ewla
weal
```